# Does a class behave different for two different teachers?

Tags: mixed-model, multilevel-analysis

How can I express the question as a model:
Imagine there is a class and you want to track the performance of the pupils when the teacher in a specific subjects changes. 
I guess this can be done with a lmer model, right?

I would do it as following:

```
lmer(Mark ~ test + (1 | Pupil),...)
```

but how do I consider the two different teachers?

edit: I thought a bit about it and I think the factor teacher has to be a fixed factor because teacher is not part of a pool but we're interested in the differences between both teachers. 
Hence, I derive that assumption from the treatment gender as a fixed effect, too (when differences between male and woman are from interested).

So I would think of:

```
lmer(Mark ~ test + teacher + (1 | Pupil),...)
```

Right?